# Problems with StructuredProperty and StringProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i am doing the finally degree work in Google App Engine, but i am having problems when i try this:

```
class Predicate(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    parameters = ndb.JsonProperty()

class State(ndb.Model):
    predicates = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate, repeated=True)

class Action(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    parameters = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    preconditions = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate, repeated=True)
    predicatesToAdd = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate, repeated=True)
    predicatesToDel = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate, repeated=True)

class Plan(ndb.Model):
    plan = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate, repeated=True)

class Problem(ndb.Model):
    initialState = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate)
    goalState = ndb.StructuredProperty(Predicate)
    actions = ndb.StructuredProperty(Action, repeated=True)
```

i get this error:

```
TypeError: This StructuredProperty cannot use repeated=True because its model class (Predicate) contains repeated properties (directly or indirectly).
```

StructuredProperty, if it contains repetitions, can not be replicated another StructuredProperty. But I need this structure models. How can i solve this?

And sorry for my bad english :(

---

I solved this problem using LocalStructuredProperty, but I think it will not work at all

Comment: Could you use a BlobProperty to store the parameters and pickle them rather than a repeated StringProperty?

Comment: If you don't need queries on that property, you can use `LocalStructuredProperty` to allow the nested "repeated".

Comment: I need the data because i use this as input parameters of an algorithm (in Python), but i don't know if with LocalStructuredProperty I have enough

Comment: Tim, i don't know what you mean :/

Comment: This is a structural problem which cannot be overcome. If you explain the problem statement, we might be able to suggest a different data structure

Comment: I have an algorithm which need next information: An initial state, a goal state, and a set of actions. I am implementing the algorithm into the webpage, and i need the structures (http://pastebin.com/sxh462Md) but i don't know how to solve the problem after use JsonProperty in Predicate.

Comment: You could also store your `Actions` entity independently and use `actions = ndb.KeyProperty(Action, repeated=True)` to reference them in your `Problem` entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your design is that ndb does not allow nested repeated properties. In other words, you cannot have a repeated structured property, which in turn has its own repeated property. If you remove the repeated=True from the parameters property, it will work.

You will need to re-think your design to work around this. One possible solution may be to use a JsonProperty for parameters, and store the list of strings as a JSON string. You won't be able to query them then of course, but it may work out depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but i need show the parameters and use it in an algorithm, i could use JsonProperty for this?

Comment: Potentially, yes. You just can't run datastore queries against individual strings or objects in a JsonProperty. If you were to load the entity in memory, then you can parse the JSON string, and use the values in whatever algorithms you like.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this, i have other question about GAE, i need take information from an html and use this in other html, how can i do it?

Comment: please create another post with details of your other question

Comment: I have the same problem with other classes, but in this case i need show in webpage the information of the high level, i cant upload with format, so i uploaded the code to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/yS0TcvYr

Comment: unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean by "i need show in webpage the information of the high level", but from looking at your code, my answer to the question still applies - you cannot have nested repeated properties. you need to rethink your design to remove them.